# iOS font freetype trueType AAT

Tags: ios, freetype

Last day, I see many thing about `iOS` text. Now I want to know, what is the real `fontType` apple use.  someOne say iOS use freeType, but I print all of the image, not fount `libFreeType`. other one say iOS use `ATT CGFont`, but this is not say very clearly.  I don't find any lib for this.  what is the real Font engine for iOS.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Information from an old-timer: historically Apple wrote the [TrueType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) first engine, and owns the rights (patents) to use it; later (1997), `Freetype` was written to broaden the access to these fonts to other devices. Then `Freetype 2` extended the API to use other formats. But `Freetype` is not the only possible rendering library, just the most common on open source systems.

Answer (score 0):

Here Apple Doc ..Please Refer this

> Apple currently provides support for drawing using AAT fonts via Apple
>   Type Services for Unicode

https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6AATIntro.html

For **The Font Engine** https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM02/Chap2.html